# Where does console output appear in TypeScriptLang.org's tutorials?

Tags: typescript, console, microsoft-edge

I am trying to learn TypeScript using the on-line tutorials at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html
using the Microsoft Edge browser (v. 44.18362.329.0, © 2019).

The first tutorial is supposed to output `"Hello World"` via `console.log()`:

```
const hello = "Hello"  
const world = "World"  
console.log(hello + " " + world)
```

But when I click the page's "Run" menu item (or press Ctrl-Enter), no output appears.  Where does TypeScript's `console.log()` output to?  And how can one see TypeScript output using the Edge browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[katamaster818](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3130072) found Microsoft's documentation for [how to open the Console in Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console#targetText=To%20open%20the%20Console%20tool,the%20top%20of%20the%20window):

> To open the Console tool in Microsoft Edge, press the F12 key to access the developer tool window (or right-click on the page, and then select **Inspect Element**). Then, select the **Console** tab at the top of the window.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was staring myself blind, your comment helped me out.